# How to fix the scale value on the plot using Python

Tags: python, list, matplotlib

I am generating a plot according to `values`. But the value on the scale as shown below is quite different (red highlighted). How do I fix the scale range such that it lies between the min and max of `values`?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import Normalize
from matplotlib.cm import ScalarMappable

# Define the number of circles in each row
# num_circles = [22, 23] #, 22, 23, 22, 23,22, 23, 22, 23, 22, 23, 22, 23, 22, 23]
# while len(num_circles) < 45:
#     num_circles.extend([22, 23])
    
num_circles=[22,23,22,23,22,23,22,23,22,23,22,23,22,23,22,23,22,23,22,23,22,23,22,23,22,23,22,23,22,23,22,23,22,23,22,23,22,23,22,23,22,23,22,23,22]

# Define the radius of the circles
radius = 0.2

# Define the values for each circle (just for demonstration)


values=[0.072, 0.072, 0.072, 0.072, 0.072, 0.0719999999999977] 

# Generate coordinates for the centers of the circles in each row
centers = []
for row, num in enumerate(num_circles):
    y_coord = 1 - row * 0.5
    x_start = 0.5 if row % 2 == 0 else 0.4
    centers.extend([(x_start + i * 0.5, y_coord) for i in range(num)])

# Calculate total rows and columns
total_rows = len(num_circles)
max_columns = max(num_circles)

# Adjust figure size and padding dynamically
fig_width = 20 #max_columns * radius * 3
fig_height = 20 #total_rows * radius * 3
padding = max(radius * 4, radius * total_rows)

# Plot the circles
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(fig_width, fig_height), dpi=500)

cmap = plt.cm.Blues  # Choose a colormap
norm = Normalize(vmin=min(values), vmax=max(values))  # Normalize the values for colormap

# Plot circles with assigned colors
for center, value in zip(centers, values):
    circle = plt.Circle(center, radius, color=cmap(norm(value)), edgecolor='black', linewidth=1.5)
    ax.add_patch(circle)

# Assign value 0.021 to all remaining circles
default_value = 0.072
for center, value in zip(centers[len(values):], range(len(values), len(centers))):
    circle = plt.Circle(center, radius, color=cmap(norm(default_value)), edgecolor='black', linewidth=1.5)
    ax.add_patch(circle)

# Add colorbar
sm = ScalarMappable(cmap=cmap, norm=norm)
sm.set_array([])
cbar = plt.colorbar(sm, ax=ax)
cbar.set_label('sigma', fontsize=25)  # Set font size here
cbar.ax.tick_params(labelsize=25)  # Set tick label size
cbar.outline.set_linewidth(1.5)  # Adjust outline width if needed

# Set the x-axis limit to accommodate the entire width of circles plus some padding
ax.set_xlim(-padding, max_columns * radius * 4 + padding)

ax.set_ylim(-padding, total_rows * radius * 3 + padding)
ax.set_aspect('equal', 'box')
plt.axis('off')

# Ensure all rows displayed are the same as len(num_circles)
plt.axis('equal')

plt.show()

# Generate coordinates for the centers of the circles in each row
centers = []
for row, num in enumerate(num_circles):
    y_coord = 1 - row * 0.5
    x_start = 0.5 if row % 2 == 0 else 0.4
    centers.extend([(x_start + i * 0.5, y_coord) for i in range(num)])

# Append all coordinates into a single list in the form of tuples
all_coordinates = centers

print("All coordinates in a single list:", all_coordinates)
```

The current output is

[image]

Comment: 150×10¹² is approximately 1 UA when expressed in millimetre, then the difference between your "different" values (`print((1-0.0719999999999977/0.072)*150E12) # 4.796`) is in proportion the same difference you have between 1 UA and 1 UA minus 5 mm. Are you sure that your numbers are sensible?